# Dataloader Export CSV Issues: how to remove quotes & add empty column

Tags: data-loader

In a requirement , I have to extract the file in .csv and copy it over to a FTP location.  I am doing it with command line dataloader and facing following issue related to it.

1) They are asking to have .csv file without "" . I mean , as per their requirement a csv should not have "".
However, apex dataloader extract the data with "".

"ID","ISDELETED","MASTERRECORDID","NAME"
"00117000002GuHwAAK","false","","Deloitte"
"00117000002YZ2EAAW","false","","Advanced Micro Computer Specialists"

as per requirement , it should be like

ID,ISDELETED,MASTERRECORDID,NAME
00117000002GuHwAAK,false,Deloitte
00117000002YZ2EAAW,false,Advanced Micro Computer Specialists

2)  Business need some extra column with Header but no value.  I don't want to create field for them.  Tt's a not design to create field just to have a column in Csv.

Comment: per your requirement - how would your CSV perform with a field value of `Advanced Micro Computer Specialists, Inc` if the quotes are removed?

Comment: It should have "".  Data loader put Column Header and data in "". I don't want in "". It has to be comma separated only.

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal Mark's point is valid. CSV format requires the use of "" to enclose values that contain comma or newline. What your client is asking for is not CSV, and also doesn't work with names that contain a comma. Dataloader can't provide it for you. Not an SF issue, but have you asked them why they want this?

Comment: @AnkitKhandelwal what you're asking for isn't possible with Dataloader. It will properly quote values in the CSV because it's the safe thing to do. I also have never seen a CSV-consuming application that could not handle quoted values. I suspect that this requirement is misguided and would suggest that you confirm the ask.

Comment: @MarkPond I've been exporting files for months because of a data migration project we are currently dealing with and until today I have not been getting double quoted values, and now that I am it is breaking all my scripts and also can not be imported into an ArangoDB collection properly since it will perceive all these values as strings